# Getting /dev/sd* from blkid, given a PARTUUID

Tags: sed, grep, partition

I am in initramfs with no /dev/disk/by-*

I have a PARTUUID, I need to get it's block device.

Here is my output from `blkid`

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="7304-E3F2" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="05699fcc-97f6-4792-9dec-f9135552e92f"
/dev/sda2: UUID="da0ff3d2-432b-4306-8ec4-a032b934544a" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="9f6874df-b700-4e59-a83f-3ce3d4485799"
/dev/sda3: UUID="3c5275a3-a8ed-4884-bc02-a5163acc58bb" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="3505f9df-99f4-4b4c-859d-1381db86d8f0"
/dev/sdb: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
/dev/sdc: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="F066142D6613F2D8" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="cc6765e3-f0e6-4007-95ea-ac896bf8f824"
/dev/sdd2: UUID="5414-7544" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="1c635ea8-098f-4680-8e9b-1926401eb77b"
/dev/sdd3: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="c7da9e6d-ce60-4731-81cf-e332a4c88e39"
/dev/sdd4: UUID="DCFE1841FE1815FC" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="25b78542-0b82-4eef-96a0-51dda3dc4ec7"
/dev/md126: PTUUID="b4c4aef3-c86e-4719-8bbc-f101540327b8" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/md126p1: LABEL="DataWindows" UUID="088E077E8E076412" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="c70196d3-60fc-4211-9b2a-4ad47a206957"
/dev/md126p2: LABEL="DataLinux" UUID="47ea9736-2de7-40ba-bf05-9660484ceea0" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Microsoft basic data" PARTUUID="86610416-00ce-4e8e-8682-4a46e4cae0da"
/dev/sde1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="efi" UUID="0A3E-9ABE" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="msdos" PARTUUID="3948166f-7d1b-4b75-ad77-5ed5ad5f8e37"
/dev/sde2: LABEL="platform" UUID="7503d533-1a0c-47ed-9048-e96c7810bb0a" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="platform" PARTUUID="9d69c3d4-4175-4a46-baba-64f95bcea861"
/dev/sde3: LABEL="data" UUID="9a589cce-1d27-4d60-9589-d0cbae228517" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="data" PARTUUID="79067919-3db0-4c63-b78e-b72ce880cd42"
```

Using `sed` or `grep`, how would I get `/dev/sda1` from `05699fcc-97f6-4792-9dec-f9135552e92f`?

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use the matching feature of `blkid`.

Example:

```
$ blkid --match-token PARTUUID=05699fcc-97f6-4792-9dec-f9135552e92f -o device
/dev/sda1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `GNU Awk` for this, using its `match()` function and match the capture group to the array. Here `$NF` represents the last column value containing the first column value as `/dev/sda1:`

```
blkid | awk '$1=="/dev/sda1:" && match($NF,/PARTUUID=\"(.*)\"/, arr){print arr[1]; exit}'
05699fcc-97f6-4792-9dec-f9135552e92f
```

(or) if you want to use `05699fcc-97f6-4792-9dec-f9135552e92f` and get `/dev/sda1` you do the following.

```
blkid | awk '/PARTUUID=\"05699fcc-97f6-4792-9dec-f9135552e92f\"/{sub(/[:]$/,"",$1); print $1}'
/dev/sda1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using grep+cut it would be:

```
blkid | grep 05699fcc-97f6-4792-9dec-f9135552e92f | cut -d ":" -f1
```

and using grep+sed:

```
blkid | grep 05699fcc-97f6-4792-9dec-f9135552e92f | sed -e 's/^\(.*\):.*$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` everything becomes easier:

```
blkid | sed -r '/05699fcc-97f6-4792-9dec-f9135552e92f/!d;s/(^\/.*\/.*):.*/\1/'
```

Output will be:

```
/dev/sda1
```

**Explanation**:

My `sed` approach can be devided at two parts. The first is:

```
sed '/05699fcc-97f6-4792-9dec-f9135552e92f/!d
```

This is simple pattern accordance - delete all line except matching.

The second part devided with `;`:

```
sed -r 's/(^\/.*\/.*):.*/\1/'
```

and it use a simple `sed` substitution pattern `s/pattern/replace_pattern/` but with index placed in `()`. The `\1` is only link to pattern in `()`. See [this](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#toc-uh-4) tutorial.